# python access self in dll callback function in class

Tags: python, ctypes

i have a dll function of some api like this:

```
def dllcallback(items):
  pass
```

i want to access self in class functions linked with dll callback.

```
class myobject(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 999
  @dllcallback
  def mycallback(self, items):
    print (self.a)
    self.a = 888
    print (self.a)
```

i don't think dllcallback accepts self as argument. so this was fail.
i wish myobject.mycallback will trigger when dllcallback is called by api, and shows:

```
999
888
```

and i tried the below to make 'self' be accessible by inner functions, but this approach killed the Kernel...

```
class myobject(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 999
  def callbacks(self):
    @dllcallback
    def mycallback(items):
      print (self.a)
      self.a = 888
      print (self.a)
```

i am not sure the reason why the kernel died. thanks in advance for any suggestion.

***UPDATED: 20180912 1436***

Actually, the override method could be called without self as argument,

```
class myobject(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 999
  @dllcallback
  def mycallback(items):
    global self
    print (self.a)
    self.a = 888
    print (self.a)

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I suppose 'self' cannot be obtained like this...any suggestions?

***UPDATED: 20180913 1645***

Got some progress in writing a class including ctypes dll callback functions

```
class myobject(object):
  def __init__(self):
    if u'32bit' in architecture(): # 32bit WinOS
      self.spdll = windll.LoadLibrary('XXX.dll')
    else:                          # 64bit WinOS
      self.spdll = cdll.LoadLibrary('XXX.dll')
    self.a = 999

  def callbacksinit(self):
    def mycallback(items):
      print (self.a)
      self.a = 888
      print (self.a)
    self.mycallbackaddr = WINFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p) 

  def regcallbacks(self):
    self.spdll.APICALLBACK(self.mycallbackaddr)
```

With this code, i can access self.a when mycallback is triggered by API. 
And fortunately for me, self.a can be changed to 888 after mycallback is done without global declaration (e.g. global self) in mycallback.
I have no idea why this happens...why WINFUNCTYPE(None, c_char_p) works in this way and why self.a can be changed without global declaration. I leave this question open a while and maybe someone can clear my doubts.

Comment: a callback cannot be a method. Have to carry context/class information when calling the callback. For instance, why not passing an unique ID in the parameters, and this ID is linked to the class instance through a dictionary?

Comment: i wonder if you have some examples...are you suggesting to pull the override method mycallback out of the class?

Comment: FYI, on 64-bit `windll` and `cdll` have no difference, so you don't need the `if u'32bit'` hack.  Also, `self.spdll = WinDLL('XXX')` is all you need, assuming you are using `__stdcall` on your functions in the DLL.  Use `CDLL('XXX')` if functions are `__cdecl`.

Comment: your comment is great. I went into very much trouble without know it last few weeks with my old laptop. anywayz, any comments on my approach? will there be any potential flaw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your update is a valid solution.  You can update `self` because it is mutable.  You don't need a `global` (or in this case, `nonlocal`) declaration to access it.  You only need those to *reassign* the variable.

For example:

```
def func():
    L = []

    def inner():
        #nonlocal L  # Uncomment to work
        L = [1,2,3]  # Reassign L

    inner()          # Call the function and attempt to modify L
    return L

def func2():
    L = []

    def inner():
        L[:] = [1,2,3] # Mutate L

    inner()            # Call the function and attempt to modify L
    return L

print(func())
print(func2())
```

Output:

```
[]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here's a full working example of your approach...

**test.c**

```
#include <wchar.h>
#define API __declspec(dllexport)

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(const wchar_t*);

API void do_callback(CALLBACK cb)
{
    cb(L"one");
    cb(L"two");
    cb(L"three");
}
```

**test.py**

```
from ctypes import *

CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None,c_wchar_p)

class Test:
    dll = CDLL('test')
    dll.do_callback.argtypes = CALLBACK,
    dll.do_callback.restype = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def get_callback(self):

        @CALLBACK
        def callback(s):
            self.count += 1     # nonlocal, but mutable
            print(self.count,s)

        return callback

    def do(self):
        self.dll.do_callback(self.get_callback())

t = Test()
t.do()
```

Output:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

Comment: thanks pointing out self is mutable variable as self was a mystery to me. Originally, i wish to keep tons of cfunction defined in separated file and use @CALLBACK to create class with only the requires. i suppose it is naive becoz i have to load dll somewhere and seem the best place is within the class so as to have a clean deletion if necessary.

Comment: This method worked great for a complex interface when others failed me. The only modification I needed to make was to save a reference to the callback on the class before passing it to the C layer. This was important to make sure callback would not get garbage collected before it was called from C.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a magic way to find the method+instance in a callback. But when you're interfacing with another language, that's another story.

Not sure if you can do better than:

- registering your object in a global (well, class-instance) dictionary
- create a callback wrapping *function* that finds the id (that your caller has to know) and calls the method with the proper context

You can keep all static objects inside the class scope for a cleaner solution.

like this:

```
class myobject(object):
  globdict = {}
  id = 0
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 999
    self.id += 1   # this id will have to be passed to the foreign library
    myobject.globdict[self.id] = self

  def mycallback(self, items):
    print (self.a)

  @staticmethod
  def real_callback(id,items):
     # first parameter is the object, then the "items" argument
     # using function-call style (not object)
     # id may need to be converted back from `ctypes`
     myobject.mycallback(myobject.globdict[id],items)
```

Comment: can someone explain the downvote? any concurrent better answers? any technical information to back up the downvote? I'm really interested.

Comment: well, until someone comes up with a better solution. I know this isn't ideal.