# Using a class method as a function callback Ctypes

Tags: python, methods, ctypes

I am trying to use a class method as a callback function from a API via ctypes. I followed the suggestions on other posts (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52347094/12783146) but they don't seem to work for me

Bellow a minimal code

```
import ctypes as ct
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time


callback_Statusmessages = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.c_char_p)

class Controler():
    lib = ct.CDLL("Test.dll")
    lib.Setcallbacks.argtypes = (callback_Statusmessages, callback_Statusmessages, callback_Statusmessages)
    lib.Setcallbacks.restype = None
    lib.start.argtypes = None
    lib.start.restype = ct.c_int

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def InitStatusmessages(self):      
        def Statusmessages(message):
            print("===================================================================================================")
            print("Message: ", message.decode())
            print("===================================================================================================")
            time.sleep(.1) # just to slow it down.

        return callback_Statusmessages(Statusmessages)

    def Start(self):
        self.lib.Setcallbacks(self.InitStatusmessages(), self.InitStatusmessages(), self.InitStatusmessages())
        self.thread = Thread(target= self.lib.start)
        self.thread.start()   

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ctr = Controler()
    ctr.Start()
```

The current code either causes and "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception." or a "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." when the API tries to call the callback

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```py
self.lib.Setcallbacks(self.InitStatusmessages(), self.InitStatusmessages(), self.InitStatusmessages())
```

The object returned by `self.InitStatusMessages()` goes out of scope and is destroyed as soon as the above line completes execution.  It worked in the linked answer provided because the callback was used immediately before the line completed execution, but with a separate function using the callback after `Setcallbacks` returns the callback needs to persist.  Instead, create a single instance of the callback and store it in the class instance.  Pass it to `Setcallbacks`:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.cb = self.InitStatusmessages() # create persistent instance

def Start(self):
    self.lib.Setcallbacks(self.cb, self.cb, self.cb) # pass that instead
```

for testing I used the following C code:

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(const char*);

CALLBACK g_a, g_b, g_c;

API void Setcallbacks(CALLBACK a, CALLBACK b, CALLBACK c) {
    g_a = a;
    g_b = b;
    g_c = c;
}

API int start(void) {
    for(;;) {
        g_a("one");
        g_b("two");
        g_c("three");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
===================================================================================================
Message:  one
===================================================================================================
===================================================================================================
Message:  two
===================================================================================================
===================================================================================================
Message:  three
===================================================================================================
===================================================================================================
Message:  one
===================================================================================================
.
.
.
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much.  That solves the problem perfectly. Going to review my knowledge of the garbage collector!